# Como chamar minha view Asp.Net MVC com ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net, mvc, controller

Estou iniciando meus estudos com Asp.Net MVC e estou com proplemas para chamar uma view pelo menu principal. Tenho uma view inicial "_Layout" com o seguinte item de menu:

```html
<li>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" class="rd_tabs" id="tab3">
  <label for="tab3">Currículo</label>
</li>
```

E estou tentando chamar a controller/action pela seguinte forma:

```html
@section Scripts{
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#tab3').click(function () {
                    $.ajax
                        ({
                            url: "/Home/Curriculo",
                            type: 'GET',
                            success: function (dados) {
                                console.log("sucesso");
                            },
                            error: function (erro) {
                                console.log("falha");
                            }
                        });
                });
            })
    </script>
}
```

Mas nada acontece, mesmo a function sendo executada e imprimindo "sucesso" no console. Já tentei chamar a url de formas diferentes mas nada deu certo.

Gostaria a ajuda dos colegas para saber onde estou errando. 
Obrigado!

Comment: Bom tenta em vez de sucesso mandar o console imprimir os dados e olha se não existe um código html, o que acontece e que ele retorna na mesma página os dados você teria que fazer alguma coisa com a página retornada.

Comment: Sim, ele retorna a pagina, mas eu não sabia que teria que tratar o retorno. Imaginei que a própria action chamaria a pagina.

Answer (score 1):

Bom tenta em vez de sucesso mandar o console imprimir os dados e olha se não existe um código html, o que acontece e que ele retorna na mesma página os dados você teria que fazer alguma coisa com a página retornada.

Acho que não precisa do ajax faz assim.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tab3').click(function () {
              window.location = "/Home/Curriculo"  

        });
    })
```

Comment: Eureca, funcionou com  sua dica Rodrigo! Value amigo , obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Legal, não esquece de votar.